# Angular 4 animated dropdown menu

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, drop-down-menu

I saw this in web.whatsapp.com

[image]

Is there any packages in angular? to achieve the exact look of the drop down menu?

If is not. ¿How can I do it with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the above task using primeng library.
you can get more information on this link.

[[1]: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown][1]

you have to override the primeng css. using ng:deep